# Text to Date Conversion Error C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

When coding a C# default.aspx.cs file I added a method that converts a text string into date/time. 
However I get the following error

> Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

Here is the code I have.

```
       //populate the form
        txtReldate.Text = vidgame.ReleaseDate.ToString();
       //Conversion Method
         vidgame.ReleaseDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtReldate.Text);
```

Comment: Can you share the string you are converting?

Comment: None of these lines will produce the error you mention. The error means that you tried to assign a Date value to a string variable or property. Where does the error occur? What is the call stack of the exception?

Comment: is `vidgame.ReleaseDate` a `string` or `DataTime`?

Comment: Can you post the definition of `vidgame`. Looks like the `vidgame.ReleaseDate` property is a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the error provided, `ReleaseDate` is not a `DateTime` here.

```
vidgame.ReleaseDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtReldate.Text);
```

if `ReleaseDate` is in fact a `string`, just do this:

```
vidgame.ReleaseDate = txtReldate.Text;
```

Comment: @cianz182, I'm glad I could be of assistance! Please consider marking it as the answer for yourself, myself, and the community when the timer elapses and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Please mention the string so that we could help you .. however here is a good tutorial to convert datetime into string and vice versa.

[Convert Datetime to String](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14743/Easy-String-to-DateTime-DateTime-to-String-and-For)